# Apresentar a expressão de derivada em Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, matemática

Estou usando o pacote "Extreme Optimization" para aprender a utilizar cálculo e matematica mais avançada nos programas usando a linguagem VB.
Contudo, preciso de ajuda quanto ao programa salvar na memória e apresentar ao usuário a derivada não numérica de uma expressão dada.
No caso, eu tenho, por exemplo uma expressão x^2 + x^5 e sua derivada é 2x + 5x^4. Contudo, quando tento apresentar tal expressão, o valor retornado é zero.
Segue em anexo o código. Já fiz várias modificações, mas não obtive êxito. Então, coloquei aqui o código que fiz inicialmente.
Obrigada!

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Dim x As Double

    Dim result As Double = FunctionMath.Derivative(AddressOf Differentiation, x)

    MessageBox.Show("diferenciacao em x  = " + result.ToString, "resultado", MessageBoxButtons.OK)

End Sub

Function Differentiation(ByVal x As Double) As Double

    Return Math.Pow(x, 2) + Math.Pow(x, 5)

End Function
```

Comment: Não seria porque `x` vale 0?

Comment: Assim, teoricamente não deveria. Pode ser que eu não esteja sabendo acrescentar alguma linha de código impedindo que o programa interprete desta forma...

Comment: Verifique o valor de retorno da sua função. Double retornado por Differentiation() é um float de precisão dupla.